# Change Interval from 5 seconds to specific time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

```
timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                        target:self 
                                      selector:@selector(onTimer) 
                                      userInfo:nil 
                                       repeats:YES];
```

Can I change the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to a specific time in the day? Without changing a lot of the code I already have?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is your friend:

```
timer = [[[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:myDate interval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] autorelease];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Just note if the app isn't *running* at that particular time, you won't get fired - so don't count on this for "long term" events.